# How to run Flutter web app on my Mobile browser

Tags: git, flutter, dart, github, hosting

I developed a Flutter web app using **Flutter beta channel** and works fine on browser; Now I want to test how it looks on phone, I want to run it on mu mobile browser.
Can anyone help help how I should do that?
I am really confused and I don't know what to do.. please I need help

Comment: Thank you.. Maybe it needs more detail, I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to publish folder to firebase and open that URL into your mobile browser

please refer to this blog.
https://medium.com/flutter/must-try-use-firebase-to-host-your-flutter-app-on-the-web-852ee533a469

after host, you can check on mobile

Comment: uh , so I have to host on firebase, there is no way to check it on local device

Comment: yes, there is a way to just run code. goto mobile browser and type your hosted laptop or desktop IP with a port. But there is one condition for it mobile and desktop or laptop should be the same network prefer same wifi.

Comment: Uh ok, thank you for the help

Comment: @mihirpipermitwala I've tried you solution but no..it didn't work

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery can I get your issues?

Comment: @mihirpipermitwala I've tried your solution on debug files of the web but it return timeout on my mobile browser ...I'll try to create a localhost using python server on the release files of the web project maybe the timeout problem will be fixed using that approach

Comment: also it didn't work on the release files..it return timeout..by the way I've use https://ngrok.com/ to convert my machine to a host and access it via internet network and it worked like a charm

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery thanks I appreciate